# Angular 2 patchValue inserts only first object of nested array

Tags: angular

I have a form in a model driven approach. In this form there is a nested Array like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.reproOrderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    ...
    anyArray: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        anyValue: []
      })
    ])
  });
}
```

When I have an object and make patchValue on this form only the first object ist filled into the form.

```
{
    anyArray:[
         {anyValue:"test"},
         {anyValue:"asdf"}
    ]
}
```

So in this case only {anyValue:"test"} is available in my form after patchValue. Is this a known bug or even on purpose? It doesn´t make sense to me.

Comment: how your patchValue looks like ?

Comment: this.reproOrderForm.patchValue({
    anyArray:[
         {anyValue:"test"},
         {anyValue:"asdf"}
    ]
});

Comment: did u figure this out? i have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t use patchValue for populating an array in your formgroup. Instead you have to push the values onto the formgroup array by using a for-loop.